# PHP check if a file has been fully uploaded

Tags: php, centos, centos6

I have users who upload files through FTP to some directory, And I want to check with PHP if the file has been fully uploaded.

For example, if I am uploading a file, and it's still uploading, I don't want to do anything with this file, I want the loop to `continue`.

This is my loop:

```
foreach($files as $f) {
    if($f == "." OR $f == "..") continue;
    if(!preg_match("@\.filepart^@", $f)) {
        // Here I want to check if the file has been fully uploaded
        // Something like: if($fileInUse) continue;
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Operation System: CentOS 6

Comment: Use a conditional statemement for the [**uploading function**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), or use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The files uploaded via `FTP`, not `HTTP POST`

Comment: My mistake. Have a read at http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ftp-put.php where they state *"if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't upload the files with code (the files uploaded via FTP client like `FileZilla`), I just want to check with the code if they have been fully uploaded.

Comment: Ok, well that should have been originally posted in your question. What you'll need to do then, is to check using [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-exists.php), least that's what I think you need to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The file does exists. It's just not fully uploaded...

Comment: You can't tell this information without knowing what the file is ahead of time.

Comment: If you know the file size you can check for that. If you know the file's contents you might be able to check for validity. Without knowing something of that sort you simply cannot tell that it is finished. You could try looking for the uploading process being gone but that's not necessarily possible or a good indication.